# What is the difference between those two statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between those two statements?

A:

```
$(document.getElementById('timer-' + endTimes[i].nid)).removeClass('hidden-timer').text('');
```

B:

```
$('#timer-' + endTimes[i].nid).removeClass('hidden-timer').text('');
```

**[EDIT]**

Thanks for all responses.

`endTimes[i].nid` is numeric, ex `340`.

The most important difference for me was that line A is causing a WSOD, but line B works fine.

Comment: practically nothing, B will immediately figure out that you're looking up by id and do a document.getElementById and then everything else is identical.

Comment: Use your DOM inspector to compare the end result of each method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both do the same, except that the selector can mess up with special characters: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Mwrpb/.

```
var id = "a:b";

$(document.getElementById('timer-' + id)).text('abc');
// works, 'timer-a:b' means an id of 'timer-a:b' here

$('#timer-' + id).text('def');
// won't work: '#timer-a:b' means an id of 'timer-a' with pseudo class 'b' here
```

Comment: +1 That's a worthful point (Jquery use : as filter of objecttypes from name).

Answer (score 1):

They're both jQuery (a layer above your DOM, and above Javascript), and they're both equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is using the DOM method of identifying an element with a given ID.  The second one is using the jQuery way.  The second one is better here, I'm not even sure the first one would work.

Comment: They're *both* jQuery.  One goes through the DOM; the other is straight jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively nothing.

The first passes a DOM node to the jQuery selector and builds a jQuery object.

The second instructs jQuery to build a jQuery object by element ID.

Use the 2nd, for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

A: `document.getElementById('timer')` is a normal Javascript method for which you would not need JQuery.

B: `$('#timer')` is JQuery shorthand for `document.getElementById('timer')`.

If you are going to use JQuery, I'd suggest sticking with option B.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with your second point. The `$` way returns a jQuery object, whereas `document.getElementById` returns a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery, 
You don't need to specify document.getElementById. Jquery is there to do that work for you. If you need to take objects through pure JavaScript, you have to use document.getElementById (getElementByName and so on..)